# Phone calls to different numbers depending on user's location

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I'm developing an app that will be able to sense the user's location and then call a specific phone-number depending on that location.

I have this method for the actual phone call,
 `- (IBAction)phone { [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:123"]];`

Then I have this method for getting the user's location.

```
 NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
    if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
        placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
        _addressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                             placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                             placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                             placemark.administrativeArea,
                             placemark.country];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
    }


} ];
```

Depending on the user's "placemark.locality", I want to make the phone call to a different number.
Any ideas?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a `NSDictionary` mapping localities with phone numbers, for example:

```
NSDictionary *localityToPhoneNumber = @{"Paris": @"+338123710", @"London": @"+412345678"};
```

Then you can get the phone number that belongs to a locality and dial it:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [localityToPhoneNumber objectForKey:placemark.locality];
NSString *tel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:tel];
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing this is a best-practice question:
Map to an `NSDictionary`, then select by `placemark.locality`, then place the call.

```
NSDictionary *map = @{
                      @"New York" : @"+1 212-226-3126",
                      @"San Francisco" : @"+1 415-392-0202"
                      };

if ([[map allKeys] containsObject:placemark.locality])
{ phoneNumber = [map objectForKey:placemark.locality]; }
```